Why is the JWT token not used for authorization in Payara micro
I have followed this example here https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.183/documentation/payara-server/public-api/openid-connect-support.html to add authentication and authorization to my application. However, when I try to call the application with the JWT token in the Authorization header (Authorization: Bearer ey...) it fails and redirects me back to authenticating.
I have this in code:
@ApplicationPath("/")
@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition(
        providerURI = "https://my-idp.com/auth",
        clientId = "my-app-id",
        clientSecret = "my-app-secret",
        redirectURI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/oauth2/callback",
        scope = "openid"
)
@DeclareRoles({"my_role"})
public class MyApp extends Application {

}

Then for my resource I have:
@Path("/my")
@RequestScoped
public class TestResource {

    @Context
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @GET
    @Path("resource")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("my_role")
    public String getName() {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}

Does this mean that this feature is not available on Payara micro?
If so, then why does the authorization part work?

This is the solution that I ended up doing for my question. I removed the OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition annotation and implemented these interfaces as a solution:
Custom http authentication mechanism:
@Default
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("oauth2")
public class CustomHttpAuthenticationMechanism implements javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.HttpAuthenticationMechanism { ... }

Custom identity store:
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
public class CustomIdentityStore implements javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore { ... }

Custom credential:
class CustomTokenCredential implements javax.security.enterprise.credential.Credential { ... }

Custom principal:
public class CustomPrincipal extends javax.security.enterprise.CallerPrincipal implements javax.security.enterprise.credential.Credential { ... }

